# How to get data having values at range using "between" clause in report's query?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have two parameters in the query done for JasperReports's report.

Something like this:

```
select * from customer where custid between $P{param1} and $P!{param2}
```

How can I print all the customer ids that comes in the parameter?
So, suppose I entered cust id 1 in paramid1 and 10 in paramid2. 
Now, data the generated will contain all the custids from 1 to 10.
 I need to print these custids.

I can't use field since one customer id is associated with mutiple items.

Comment: `I can't use field since one customer id is associated with mutiple items.` - You can also look at the `$X{IN}` expression

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$X{BETWEEN, <column_name>, <left_parameter_name>, <right_parameter_name>}` expression to get values in some range.

### The example

#### The report's template

I used the *"Sample DB"* dataapter from Jaspersoft Studio (*JSS*) to build this report.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Between usage example" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Sample DB"/>
    <parameter name="minId" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[10248]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="maxId" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[10260]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT shipcity, orderid FROM orders WHERE $X{BETWEEN, orderid, minId, maxId} ORDER BY orderid]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="shipcity" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="orderid" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="278" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[CIty]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="278" y="0" width="277" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Order Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="278" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{shipcity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="278" y="0" width="277" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{orderid}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

In this example the items with orderid less than the value of `maxId` parameter and greater than the value of `minId` parameter are fetched from DB.

#### The generated output

The generated at *JSS* output will be:

[image: Preview via JSS]

### Another expressions

#### Get values at inclusive range

In this case the expression will be:

`WHERE $X{[BETWEEN], orderid, minId, maxId}` - **`minId ≤ orderid ≤ maxId`**.

#### Get values at exclusive range

In this case the expression will be:

`WHERE $X{BETWEEN, orderid, minId, maxId}` - **`minId < orderid < maxId`**.

#### Get values at range, inclusive left boundary and exclusive right boundary

In this case the expression will be:

`WHERE $X{[BETWEEN, orderid, minId, maxId}` - **`minId ≤ orderid < maxId`**.

#### Get values at range, exclusive left boundary and inclusive right boundary

In this case the expression will be:

`WHERE $X{BETWEEN], orderid, minId, maxId}` - **`minId < orderid ≤ maxId`**.

#### Get values less than or equal to

In this case the expression will be:

`WHERE $X{LESS], orderid, maxId}` - **`orderid ≤ maxId`**.

#### Get values less than

In this case the expression will be:

`WHERE $X{LESS, orderid, maxId}` - **`orderid < maxId`**.

#### Get values greater than or equal to

In this case the expression will be:

`WHERE $X{[GREATER, orderid, minId}` - **`orderid ≥ minId`**.

#### Get values greater than

In this case the expression will be:

`WHERE $X{GREATER, orderid, minId}` - **`orderid > minId`**.

### More information

More details about the query syntax can be found [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/index.html#query)